# Elm: Access value of custom type

Tags: elm

I have a custom type in Elm to handle error branching. Basically, I have an input, which gives `String`s and I need to convert it to `Int`s.

```
type Seconds
    = Error Int
    | Valid Int

type alias Model =
    { timeBetweenExercises : Seconds
    , roundsSequenceOne : Seconds
    , roundsSequenceTwo : Seconds
    , roundsSequenceThree : Seconds
    , repititionsPerExercise : Seconds
    , secondsPerExercise : Seconds
    , totalTrainingDuration : Seconds
    }


init : Model
init =
    { timeBetweenExercises = Valid 3
    , roundsSequenceOne = Valid 3
    , roundsSequenceTwo = Valid 3
    , roundsSequenceThree = Valid 3
    , repetitionsPerExercise = Valid 6
    , secondsPerExercise = Valid 6
    , totalTrainingDuration = Valid 6
    }
```

I got the idea for the custom type from [Evan's "Life of a file" talk](https://youtu.be/XpDsk374LDE?t=1116). I want to remember the number when there is an error (e.g. a user entered a string instead of a number). Here is the attempt at my update function:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        TimeBetweenExercisesChanged newTime ->
            case String.toInt newTime of
                Nothing ->
                    { model | timeBetweenExercises = Error model.timeBetweenExercises }

                Just time ->
                    { model | timeBetweenExercises = Valid time }
```

My problem is, that the compiler yells at me because because `model.timeBetweenExercises` is of type `Seconds`. Is there a way I can only get the `Int` value of the custom type?

Comment: I would say the type error is clear enough, but I can't say how to fix it because I don't understand what you're trying to do. I would guess you just want to leave your model unchanged in the `Nothing` case? I certainly don't see much else you can do - but as I said I don't really know what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the model is wrong, for two reason:

1. If you have a value that is common across all cases, it's usually more convenient to move it out and up a level.
2. Your update function suggests that the `Error` state doesn't actually describe the value it holds, as you're just throwing away `newTime` if invalid and using the old time for the `Error` case instead.

Based on that, I'd suggest the following model instead:

```
type alias TimeInput =
    { seconds: Int
    , state: TimeInputState
    }

type TimeInputState = Error | Valid

type alias Model =
    { timeBetweenExercises : TimeInput
      ...
    }
```

and to change your update function to this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        TimeBetweenExercisesChanged newTime ->
            case String.toInt newTime of
                Nothing ->
                    { model
                        | timeBetweenExercises = 
                            { seconds = model.timeBetweenExercises.seconds
                            , state = Error
                            }
                    }

                Just time ->
                    { model
                        | timeBetweenExercises = 
                            { seconds = time
                            , state = Valid
                            }
                    }
```

Otherwise, you could always just make a function to extract the `Int` no matter the case:

```
getSeconds : Seconds -> Int
getSeconds time =
    case time of
        Error seconds -> seconds
        Valid seconds -> seconds
```